# Segmentation Fault in string-splitting function

Tags: c, gcc

I am not sure what is wrong with my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* splitstr(char* str, int part, char search) {
    char* out;
    int i;
    int result = 0;
    for(i=0; str[i]!='\0'; i++) {
        if(str[i] == search) {
            result = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(result == 0) {
        if(part == 1) {
            return str;
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
    int j;
    int k;
    if(part == 2) {
        for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            out[j] = str[j];
        }
        out[j] = '\0';
    } else {
        for(k = 0,j = i+1; j <= strlen(str)-1; j++, k++) {
            out[k] = str[j];
        }
        out[k] = '\0';
    }
    return out;
}   
}

int main() {
    printf("Starting program:\n");
    char* str = "Hello World!";
    char* a = splitstr(str, 1, ' ');
    char* b = splitstr(str, 1, ' ');
    printf("A is %s\n", a);
    printf("B is %s\n", b);
}
```

It returns the following output:

```
Starting program:
Segmentation Fault: 11
```

After debugging with `gdb`, I have found that the error is happening on line 30 (by using breakpoints), on the first iteration of the loop, when it tries to set `out[0]` (`out[k]`) to `str[6]` (`str[j]`). Why does this trigger a segmentation fault? I am just changing one character of a string to another!

Comment: note: the posted code has an extranious closing brace `}` after the statement: `return out;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no string in `out`. It's an uninitialized pointer, you can't write through it since there is no memory allocated for your write. Doing so triggers undefined behavior, which is why your program is crashing.

You must allocate some, typically using `malloc()`.

Also as a mere review-type note, the first loop is equivalent to:

```
const int result = strchr(str, search) != NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

the main problem is this line:

```
char* out;
```

only declares a pointer but doesn't set that pointer to point to any specific memory (that the application owns)

So this line:

```
out[j] = str[j];
```

is assigning values to some random location in memory.

Correct that problem via either:

```
char *out[ strlen( str ) +1 ];   // uses variable length array feature
```

or via:

```
char *out = malloc( strlen(str) +1 );
if( !out )
{ // malloc failed
    perror( "malloc failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, malloc successful
```

Your compiler should have told you about this problem with a statement like:

```
filename.c:43:16: warning: 'out' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
```

When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.

(for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu11` )

If you use the `-Wconversion` option, then this will also be output by the compiler:

```
filename.c:51:30: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expression [-Wsign-compare]
```